# Mask background image subtraction canvas(pure js if possible)

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, background

So I need to subtract background and foreground in plain js if possible,
things I do now:

1. Creating background image
2. Getting new videoframes to canvas
3. Converting each pixel from rgb to hsv

First I tried plain pix diff, this works, but as expected, if background light changes (when we place something) background on current frame becomes different with background on our initial back frame.

I treid this solution, but seems doing something wrong(but it can calculate background light change at least)
https://journals.ekb.eg/article_33036_aa44234dc26ac29ff40a13b5a8ad2d19.pdf
first of all I can't understand how to calculate treshold values for different backgrounds,
second what does it mean, "calculating background model with max and min values in different domains" I have one background picture, min maxing it's current vals, like 12,6 - min:12, max: 13 ?
and inter-frame ratio what does it means? I store data of previous frame, but should it be diff of current and previous frame? abs diff or what? inter-frame ration should it be background/current or current/background or current/previous, previous/current frames?

Is there any other good alghoritm which can subtract (detect) foreground with background with one background picture?

Comment: what is "plain pix diff" do you calculate the difference of correspoding pixels' values? please  what is "min maxing its current vals"  Is there any particular reason why you express mathematical operations with incomplete words? you're creating unnecessary confusion.

Comment: further you quote  "calculating background model with max and min values in different domains" I cannot even find the first word of your "quote" in the linked document.

Comment: @Piglet yeah, plain pix diff = | background(H,S,V) - current(H,S,V) | > some treshold (0.1 worked for me)
sorry, I meant, getting maximal and minimal values of background pixels HSV values of each pixel.

quote is "We build our background model with the minimum value"